# String não está sendo gravada em um arquivo de texto

Tags: c, string, arquivo

Fiz esse código cuja finalidade é ler uma string qualquer (De tamanho máximo 30), e de gravar essa string em um arquivo de texto. Após ler a string, o programa é encerrado normalmente (Sem dar erros), mas ao verificar o arquivo "teste.txt", nota-se que nada está sendo gravado nele. Como posso resolver esse problema?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *arq;
    int i;
    char nome[30];

    arq = fopen("teste.txt","w");

    if(arq = NULL){
        printf("Não é possível utilizar este arquivo");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Informe um nome:");
    scanf("%s",nome);

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(nome); i++)
        fputc(nome[i], arq);

    fclose(arq);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não vejo nada de errado em seu programa. A única coisa a observar é que se você deseja efetivamente gravar um string então está faltando gravar o caractere terminador '\0' final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O if que você colocou está definindo o ponteiro do arquivo como nulo ao invés de verificar se ele é nulo.
`if(arq = NULL)`
Troca por: 
`if(arq == NULL)`